# How to create a internal repository that cache all artifacts from remote repository?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a internal artifact repository. How can I make it cache all the artifacts from a remote repository that my project need. So that next time when my project built, all artifacts downloaded from my internal repository instead of remote repository.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider refining your original question, rather than asking it a second time. Multiple questions on the same topic make it harder for others to find answers when searching SO.

Comment: It's actually the third time you ask the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way things work.

The artifacts that your project needs are cached locally in the `.m2` folder of the machine where you perform the maven build, once they have been fetched from your maven repository(ies).

Repositories like Artifactory and Nexus act as a *repository* of the artifacts you build and a *proxy* (not repository) to other maven repositories. Hence you can use them as a single source of external artifacts for your builds.

Comment: Thank you! So what is different between proxy and remote repository in Artifactory?